# Resource to implement Block Lanczos in python;.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, prime-factorization, python

I am trying to implement GNFS in python and I wanted to make it as fast as possible just because. I am trying to find a resource that will help me implement Block Lanczos but so far haven't seen many papers on the subject. Can someone please direct me to a good one that will help me somewhat understand and implement the algorithm? Thanks.

Comment: By GNFS, do you mean "General Number Field Sieve"?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean.

Comment: Check the IMSL libraries if you have access to it. They may have a routine that does Block Lanczos.

Answer (score 1):

There's an old implementation in C with extensive comments at https://web.archive.org/web/20200114212239/http://www.friedspace.com/QS/QS-2.0/lanczos.c as part of SIMPQS. It is adapted from Jason Papadopoulos's implementation, presumably an earlier instance of https://github.com/radii/msieve/tree/master/common/lanczos.